# Commits seem to get lost when using git filter-branch to change author info

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I need to change the author info in a Github repository with one author committing using different names and emails, so for example the output of `git shortlog -sne` might be:

```
5 xy    <xy@mail.com>
5 xy z  <xy@mail.com>
5 xy    <z@mail.com>
5 xy z  <z@mail.com>
```

Afterwards, I would like to have something like

```
20 xy z <xy@mail.com>
```

I have been using `git filter-branch` as described [here](https://help.github.com/en/articles/changing-author-info). I have done this lots of times actually and never had a problem with it.
However, some of the commits seem to get lost and while changing the author info works, less commits are shown:

```
15 xy z <xy@mail.com>
```

As a side note, I don't if that's important, all of this happens on a branch which is not master.

**I would like to know 2 things:**

1. Why does this happen?
2. How can I find out which of the commits got lost?

**Edit**

As stated above, I used the bash script from [this link](https://help.github.com/en/articles/changing-author-info), so for example:

```
#!/bin/sh

git filter-branch --env-filter '

OLD_EMAIL="z@mail.com"
CORRECT_NAME="xy z"
CORRECT_EMAIL="xy@mail.com"

if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
then
    export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
    export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
fi
if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL" = "$OLD_EMAIL" ]
then
    export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
    export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
fi
' --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags
```

**Edit 2**

For clarity, I ran above code again, only changing:

```
OLD_EMAIL="xy@mail.com"
CORRECT_NAME="xy z"
CORRECT_EMAIL="xy@mail.com"
```

Comment: What's the `git filter-branch` you used? Could you please paste it in the question?

Comment: I added that to the post

Comment: The command did not touch `5 xy    <xy@mail.com>` commits as their emails are not equal to `$OLD_EMAIL`.

Comment: Yes, I ran above command more than once, adjusting `$OLD_EMAIL` and `$CORRECT_NAME`. I also actually did that twice because I thought I might have made a mistake the first time. That was not the case.